# Difficulty in traversing through a groovy node

Tags: java, groovy

I want to traverse through a groovy node that has attributes and values. For that, I would prefer a simple loop like

```
for(child in node.value())
```

The above for loop loops through all nodes but my requirement is to leave out the first element i.e `node.value()[0]` must be left out and `node.value()[1]` to the last element must be traversed.

Well, I can use a normal java loop starting with `i=1` to `node.value().size()` but I've some further issues dealing with that because I am using this loop with in a recursive function.

So, the simplicity of the loop should remain the same as above but I must be able to traverse from 2nd element to last.

I've even tried

```
for(child in node.value()[1]..node.value().size())
```

but It wasn't working.

Please tell me how to do this is groovy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for( child in node.value()[1..-1] )
```